# WSO2 API Manager change in hostname not reflecting

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying Wso2 API Manager in EC2 Ubuntu instance. When i run the ./wso2server.sh, the host name is set to the Private IP of the EC2 machine. To change that Private IP to my elastic IP i changed

```
<ServerURL>https://${carbon.local.ip}:${carbon.management.port}${carbon.context}/services/</ServerURL>
```

to

> https:// <-- elastic_IP --
>
> > :${carbon.management.port}${carbon.context}/services/

inside PRODUCT_HOME/repository/conf/carbox.xml.

This didn't solve my issue. So i replaced all ${carbon.local.ip} present inside `PRODUCT_HOME/repository/conf/` to my elastic IP, but still when i started the server i am getting 'CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL with my private IP'

can someone help me solve this issue of changing the Private_IP to elastic_IP ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying out API Manager on EC2.
This seems to be a bug in API Manager 1.0.0. Created an issue (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-703) to track the progress. Fix will be available on API Manager 1.0.1 release (scheduled to happen by mid of September 2012).